# Can code injection in Lua be performed with just a variable definition?

Tags: lua, code-injection, sanitization

Assuming I define a variable like this in Lua

`local input = "..."`

Where the `...` comes from a user-provided string. Would that user be able to perform code injection just from a variable definition? Do I need to sanitize the string?

Comment: If *you* are defining that variable, how would some other user be able to perform code injection? Are you saying that the string would be provided by said "user", and you're just pasting the "user"'s text directly into the Lua code?

Comment: Yes, the string would be user input.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, if you ever need to ask yourself if you need to sanitize your inputs, the correct answer is "yes".

As to this particular case, if you just copy/paste the user's string directly into the Lua source file, even in quotes like that, they will be able to execute arbitrary code. It's not even particularly difficult; they can provide `some text"; my_code = 20; last = "end of string`.

The best way to sanitize this is by using a long-form literal string with `[[...]]` syntax. But even that can be broken out, so you need to search through the given string for repeated sequences of the `=` character. Each time you find a sequence, note how many `=` characters are in that sequence. After searching, insert a number of `=` characters into your literal string that *isn't* one of the lengths found in the user string.

Of course, the internal implementation of Lua may have some limits on the length of the `=` sequence in a long-form literal string. In such a case, an external user could *break* your code by forcing you to use a longer sequence than the implementation supports. But it won't be able to cause arbitrary code execution; you'll just get a compile error.